# kafka mirrormaker setup to replicate data between 2 redpanda cluster

Tags: networking, amazon-eks, apache-kafka-mirrormaker, redpanda

I've deployed the redpanda in 2 EKS cluster and redpanda broker pods are up & running. One EKS cluster is in us-east-1 region and one is in us-east-2 region.

Now I need to replicate the data between 2 redpanda cluster and for that I need to setup the kafka mirrormaker on the one of the EKS clusters from that cluster the data will be replicated to the another cluster.

I am facing an issue while establishing connection between the 2 pods of redpanda broker.

I have the mirrormaker properties file like below:

`#Primary and Secondary Kafka Cluster Names
clusters=,

#Comma Saperated list of bootstrap servers for source kafka cluster
.bootstrap.servers=:9092

#Comma Saperated list of bootstrap servers for target kafka cluster
.bootstrap.servers=:9092`

I am confused what value I need to provide to . Redpanda Borkers pod IPs or the Redpanda Broker node IPs?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will have the MM2 deployed on the source cluster correct? So for the source, as long as your MM2 instance is in the same source cluster, you can use the pod ip, (recognized within the k8s cluster), but for your destination, if you are using nodeport, use the node IP.

I wrote a post explaining a little about the networking, see the "Using Kafka address and advertised Kafka address in K8s" part.
https://redpanda.com/blog/advertised-kafka-address-explanation

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I've installed mirror-maker on the source cluster. I will check the doc and will update my config file.